# Emulator removed from AVD manager when I increased sd card memory in Android Studio

Tags: flutter, android-studio

In Android studio, while creating an application, I was trying to increase the internal Storage to solve the following error, increased it from 1500mb to 5000mb, nothing changed so i increased sd card storage from 512mb to 1024mb and then the emulator got removed from avd manager list.
It still shows the emulator option in the drop down menu next to run button but clicking on that doesn't open the emulator.
How do I get the emulator back? Do i have to re-install it?

The Error:

```
Error: ADB exited with exit code 1
Performing Streamed Install

adb: failed to install D:\flutter_projects\xylophone-flutter\build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app.apk: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE]
Error launching application on AOSP on IA Emulator.
```

EDIT 1: Following this I installed a new Emulator, so does this vacate the space and other privileges that i allocated to the previous emualtor

Answer (score 0):

There are two options regarding this:
Option 1:

- try to delete the .android folder from the user directory of the system after closing the android studio and then create it.

Option 2:
Your Emulator is running out of space, clear its cache:

- Click on AVD Manager
- Wipe Data (Your Target Device )
- [Click here to see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fQ3O4.jpg)

as the error seems to be the insufficient memory related at emulator side

Comment: the problem was that the avd manager got empty, it did not have my emulator enlisted there anymore as if increasing the card memory somehow removed it altogether.
Anyhow I installed a new emulator and it's working but I still cant wrap my head around what happened.

Comment: `INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE` means you aren't having enough space, delete some apps and try again